# Asp.Net Core applications WebSocket (Client/Server)

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket

Good day.
I am planning to do WebSocket communication between two ASP.NET Core applications over HTTP (80,443).
Appendix 1 - WebSocket Server (Internet).
Appendix 2 - WebSocket client (local network, with Internet access via an HTTP proxy).
Application 1 cannot establish HTTP communication with Application 2 because application 2 is on the local network, although named Application 1 must make HTTP requests to application 2 to get some information from the local network.
For this reason, I want to use web sockets: application 2 communicates with application 1 through an HTTP proxy, a persistent connection is established. Application 1 can now send requests (its API) as text messages to the application.
In this case, only one socket (webSocket) will always be used.
Users from their browser via HTTP will make requests to application 1, and if they need some information located on the local network, application 1 (WebSocket server) will send a message to application 2 (WebSocket client) via a websocket. Several requests can be sent at the same time through the same socket.
Questions:

1. Is it necessary to enter additional identification (after all, the receiver will accept everything in a row) something like WebSocketRequestId (for example, generate a GUID)?
2. A message (request or response) via a web socket may not fit in the buffer (for example, 4 Kbytes), and it will be necessary to read the data in portions. As far as I understand, if the data is sent at the same time, it is possible that the stream will contain the beginning of the data of 1 request, the middle of 2 requests, the continuation of 1 request, the beginning of 3 requests, etc.? Those. each time a message is sent, it is necessary to split it into portions of the form WebSocketRequestId: message 4096-WebSocketRequestId.ToString (). Length?

Or is it all unnecessary actions?

Comment: You should look in to `SignalR` That handles a lot of the complications behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, using SignalR solved all the problems.